# WSO2 Api Manager - Sandbox/Production keys

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Using WSO2 Api-M On-Prem v3.1.0.

I have set up an API in Publisher with different endpoints for Production and Sandbox.
Using API Key as Application Level Security.
Enabled Security for my GET resource.

In DevPortal I created an Application and set up an subscription for my API.
Generated **Sandbox API Key** and used "Try Out" in DevPortal.
I can select Key Type "**Production**" and enter my **Sandbox Key**, I get OK response from **Production** endpoint.

[Try-Out screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5R3k.png)

If I change Key Type to **Sandbox**, I still get response from **Production** endpoint.
I see in http_access_.YYYY-MM-DD log that both requests are sent to my production endpoint.

Why isn't my request sent to Sandbox when I use Sandbox API-Key as described in documentation:

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.0.0/learn/api-gateway/maintaining-separate-production-and-sandbox-gateways/

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced this issue in API Manager version 3.1.0. This is a bug and needs to be fixed. I have created a GitHub issue for this. Please check [1].

As a workaround for your scenario, please **enable OAuth2 Application level security as well** under the Runtime Configurations of your API in Publisher. So both OAuth2 and API Key needs to be selected.

[1] https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/8483